# JavaScript getting value from a text field

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in the world of JavaScript and I want to make a app which reads the username and prints out the username in the Console Log.

```js
function OnClickButton() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById("Username");
  console.log(textarea.nodeValue);
}
```

```css
button {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color:black;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border-style: hidden;
    shape-outside: border-box;
    cursor: default;
    height: 36px;
    width: 144px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    top: 500px;
    left: 680px;
    position: absolute;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<label id="UsernameLabel" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; background-color: aliceblue;position:absolute; top: 250px;left:600px; width: 144px; height: 18px; border-radius:9px; text-align: center; font-size: medium; " >Username:</label>
  
<input type="text" id="Username"  style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; background-color: aliceblue; position: absolute; top:250px;left:760px; width:144px; height:27px; border-radius: 9px;" maxlength="10"></input>
  
<label id="PasswordLabel" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; background-color: aliceblue;position:absolute; top: 350px;left:600px; width: 144px; height: 18px; border-radius:9px; text-align: center; font-size: medium;">Password:</label>
  
<input type="password"   id="Password" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; background-color: aliceblue; position: absolute; top:350px;left:760px; width:144px; height:27px; border-radius: 9px;" maxlength="10"></input>
  
<button onclick="OnClickButton()">Sign in</button>

<script src="frontSourceCode.js"></script>
```

When I run the program every time I press on the button the NULL word is added to the Console Log.After some search it is the  `value` property of a HTML Element which returns  the output of a HTML Element however I cant find it in the list of available properties given out by VSCode.Unless the `value` property exists, which property should I search out?

Comment: Second result after pasting your title into google: [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript). Provides many possible ways to do this. Please search before asking a question.

Comment: @Marsroverr it is the linked question I had come out first before I posted down my question.As I say in the question VSCode doesnt give out the "value" property.I can load up a screenshot if you like.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the value property anyways and running the code? IDE autocomplete is useful but no substitute for reading documentation and can sometimes even be wrong.

Comment: No I havent.I will try it out.EDIT::It says "undefined" which means that the property "value" doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the `position` styles to make it so the form can be seen on stackoverflow, but just using `console.log(textarea.value)` works.

```js
function OnClickButton() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById("Username");
  console.log(textarea.value);
}
```

```css
button {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    color:black;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border-style: hidden;
    shape-outside: border-box;
    cursor: default;
    height: 36px;
    width: 144px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    /*top: 500px;
    left: 680px;
    position: absolute;*/
}

button:hover {
    background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<label id="UsernameLabel" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; background-color: aliceblue; width: 144px; height: 18px; border-radius:9px; text-align: center; font-size: medium; " >Username:</label>
  
<input type="text" id="Username"  style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; background-color: aliceblue;  width:144px; height:27px; border-radius: 9px;" maxlength="10"></input>
  
<label id="PasswordLabel" style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; background-color: aliceblue; width: 144px; height: 18px; border-radius:9px; text-align: center; font-size: medium;">Password:</label>
  
<input type="password"   id="Password" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; background-color: aliceblue;  width:144px; height:27px; border-radius: 9px;" maxlength="10"></input>
  
<button onclick="OnClickButton()">Sign in</button>

<script src="frontSourceCode.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oops.I used uppercase "V" instead of lowercase "v".

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```js
  <script>
    function OnClickButton() {
      // Get the value from the username input field
      var usernameValue = document.getElementById("Username").value;

      // Log the value to the console
      console.log("Username: " + usernameValue);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Oops.I used uppercase "V" instead of lowercase "v".